# Does the S3 BucketSizeBytes metric show bytes or bytes/day?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

The S3 Monitoring->Metrics  tab is labeled "BucketSizeBytes ( bytes / day )", which would mean that this shows the daily growth rate in bytes.

However, from the content of the graph (first image below), I think that this simply shows the number of bytes.

Further, the linked Cloudwatch chart  (second image below) has no "per day" indication.

Does "/ day" not mean "per day" but just that the x-axis is in days?

[image: S3]

[image: Cloudwatch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's just total bytes. The "/ day" probably just indicates, that the metric is collected once a day (see [Monitoring metrics with Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudwatch-monitoring.html)).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, "bytes / day" means x-axis is showing date and the y-axis is showing bucket size in bytes.